# Xamarin forms + Prism using TabbedPage with many same page

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewmodel, prism, tabbedpage

I want to use a TabbedPage in my project with many page inside.

There is what I want :

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:preparation="clr-namespace:LogiStock.UI.Tablet.Views.Preparation"
            x:Class="LogiStock.UI.Tablet.Views.Preparation.TabbedPage1" CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged">

  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    
    
    <Page1 Title="AA"/>
    <Page1 Title="BB"/>
    <Page1 Title="CC"/>
  
</TabbedPage>
```

This page has a view model and I'm using Prism for the navigation. On the first page (Title "AA"), everything is OK, but when I navigate on the second page (here the page with the title "BB"), the VM is the same as for the first page. The OnNavigatedTo method isn't triggered the second time.
It is possible to have different context for all my pages, even if its the same page with the same view model ?

Comment: You can use the `AA.BindingContext== BB.BindingContext` to check whether the instance of their viewmodels is same or not.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. You're right, it's not the same. So now I need to found how trigger the second method OnNavigatedTo

Comment: Did you set the bindingcontext in the xaml? If so, you can try to set the page's binding context in the page's construction method.

Comment: It is set in the app.xaml like this : 
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TV.Configuration.Page1, MVM.Configuration.Page1ViewModel>();

Comment: You can use the break point to check what happened when you navigated on the second page.